# Python : Need Help About Statistics

Tags: python, statistics

There is probably an answer for that but I even don't know what I am looking for. It's actually more of a statistics question than a programming question. (still I want to do it using python) Anyway here is what I want to do ;

Let's say I have a group of numbers in range of 0-999999999. I want python to change these numbers and put them in limits of 0-10.

For example, I have 3 numbers [40, 23, 456] . I want python to change these numbers according to their value in group to something like that [3 , 1 , 10].

What have I tried is ;
1- Find max number
2- Find min number
3- x = (max - min)/10
4- changednumber = (number-min)/x

That does the trick but when there is a huge gap between max number and others, values doesn't go as I want. Let's say numbers are [ 0 , 23, 500 , 24254363] in this series it goes something like [ 0, 0 , 1 , 10]. I expect it to be [0 , 1 , 5 , 10] .I must somehow involve mean of the numbers but I don't know how.

Hoping that you understand what I'm trying to accomplish ;
 - Is there any function that makes python automatically does what I'm trying to do?
 - If not, how should I make the calculations. (I was always bad with statistics)

Comment: Please explain how you are getting those numbers.  Where do `[3, 1, 10]` and `[0, 1, 5, 10]` come from?

Comment: I wrote them randomly just to give an example. To explain the example , [40 -> 3 , 23 -> 1 , 456 -> 10] I want python to make this transition according to numbers and limits I have given. Numbers are 40 , 23 , 456 and limits are 0 and 10 in this example.

Comment: That is still not explicit enough.  For instance, why does it give 3, 1, 10 instead of 2, 1, 10?

Comment: Let me explain from the beginning. I got about 30 numbers. About 20 of them are between 0-10000 , about 6 of them are between 10000-50000 , but the rest 4 of them are around 700000. I want to put all these 30 numbers in range of 0-10. Since most of them are really low numbers,I must keep in mind that mean of 30 numbers which I start with. Otherwise most numbers end up between 0-2 because 4 numbers are way higher than them.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a normalization technique called "min-max scaling"

For the more typical 0-1 normalization you would use the equation

```
          (x - min)
f(x) = -------------- 
          max - min
```

And if you want a specific range (a, b), you can simply modify the equation like so:

The equation is simply:

```
       (b-a)(x - min)
f(x) = --------------  + a
          max - min
```

And if we implement it, it looks like this:

```
def minmax_scaler(X, new_range):
    min_val = min(X)
    max_val = max(X)
    scaled = []

    for x in X: 
        numerator = (new_range[1]-new_range[0])*(x - min_val)
        denominator = max_val - min_val
        scaled.append(numerator/denominator + new_range[0])
    return scaled

print(minmax_scaler(X=[40, 23, 456], new_range=[0,10]))
```

which prints

```
[0.39260969976905313, 0.0, 10.0]
```

I think that's what you want, right?

Comment: It's tempting to think that this is what he wants, but it's not consistent with the example data he's given.

Comment: thank you for answering, this is close but unfortunetly not the exact thing I'm looking for. Using you code ;

print(minmax_scaler(X=[40, 23, 456, 38 , 40 , 51 , 13, 45 , 10], new_range=[0,10]))

If I input this, it returns [0 ,0 ,10 , 0, ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0] 

But since most numbers are low, I want my program to "normalize" it and return something like this [4, 2, 10 , 4 , 4, 5 , 1 ,4 ,1] 
I wrote this numbers as example , I didn't calculate them